# For all Real Numbers $a, b \in \mathbb R$, $|a + b|^2 = (a + b)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value, axioms

I want to show that for all real numbers $a, b \in \mathbb R$, $|a + b|^2 = (a + b)^2$. I have the following axioms for the inequality relation "$\leq$":

(i) For every $a,b \in \mathbb R$, either $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$.

(ii) If $a \leq b$ and $b \leq a$, then $a=b$.

(iii) If $a \leq b$ and $b \leq c$, then $a \leq c$.

(iv) If $a \leq b$ and $c \in \mathbb R$, then $a+c \leq b+c$.

(v)If $a \leq b$ and $0 \leq c$, then $ac \leq bc$.

I also have been given the following rules about absolute values:

(i) For all $a \in \mathbb R$, $-|a| \leq a \leq |a|$ and $a = |a|$ if, and only if, $0 \leq a$.

(ii)For all $a, b \in \mathbb R$, $|ab| = |a||b|$.

Now, I want to show that for all $a, b \in \mathbb R$, $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$.  But in part of a proof I'm reading in a textbook, it says that "$|a + b|^2 = (a+b)^2$". I understand it intuitively, but how do you prove exactly that only using the axioms and the rules above? I also know that $0 \leq |a|$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$, so that implies that $0 \leq |a + b|$, and every number squared gives a positive number. But I don't understand how to show that these two are thus equal to each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume you also have the definition of absolute value? Use case analysis: if $a + b$ is positive or zero, it's true obviously; if $a + b$ is negative, it's true almost as obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for every real $x$,

$$\vert x \vert \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \begin{cases} x &,\ x \geq 0 \\ -x &,\ x < 0 .\end{cases}$$

Now look at the two cases:

- If $ a + b  \geq 0$, we have $\vert a + b \vert = a + b$, thus $\vert
     a + b \vert^2 = (a + b)^2$.
- Otherwise, $\vert a + b \vert = - (a + b)$, therefore it follows
  $\vert a + b \vert^2 = (- (a+b))^2 = (a+b)^2$, since $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2$ for real $x,y$ and $(-1)^2 = 1$.

Comment: Correct, to the point, yet no detail omitted. My kind of proof! +1 for you. This should be accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Show that $$|c|^2=c^2$$
for all $c\in\Bbb R$ and let $c=a+b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|a+b|^2=|a+b||a+b|=|(a+b)(a+b)|=|(a+b)^2|$$ by $(\textrm{ii})$ of the absolute value.

Now, prove that $(a+b)^2\geq 0$ for all $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Why should we care about those inequalities properties for this problem? All we need are two basic properties of absolute value:

$$\begin{cases}1)\;\; |a|^n=|a^n|\,&\text{for all}\,\,\,n\in\Bbb N\\{}\\2)\;\;|a|=a &\text{forall}\,\,a\ge0\end{cases}$$

In the above, $\;a\in\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: That's not the point.

Comment: @Tim I think it is **exactly** the point of your question's title. I already read you want this to prove something else, but with the above you can prove this much...and you can check all the answers so far are very close in spirit to this one. :) You only need basic properties of *absolute value*

Comment: But I don't get how it follows from the axioms. Isn't one point of real analysis to use the axioms and previous theorems only?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|x|$ is either $x$ or $-x$

Thus for any real number $x$ we have $$|x|^2=(\pm x)^2=x^2$$

Therefore  for $x=(a+b)$ we have $$ |(a+b)|^2=(a+b)^2$$

Comment: You are simply stating as fact what is to be proved, aren't you?

Comment: I added some words to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to (i), for any $c\in\mathbb R$, either $c\le 0$ or $0\le c$.

In the case $c\le 0$, according to (iv), $c+(-c) \le 0 + -c$, that is, $0\le -c$.

So for all $c\in \mathbb R$, either $0\le c$, or $0\le -c$.

Now if $0\le c$, then according to (v), $0c\le c^2$, that is, $0\le c^2$.

And if $0\le -c$, then according to (v), $0(-c) \le (-c)^2$, that is, $0 \le c^2$ again.

So since either $0\le c$ or $0\le -c$, and in both cases it follows that $0\le c^2$, we have $0\le c^2$ for all $c\in\mathbb R$.

Now apply the rules for absolute values.